# Not able to execute batch script

Tags: batch-file

Below is the script which I am trying to execute but after double clicking on the batch file it opens command window and immediately command prompt will be disappeared.

```
CD /D C:\RAJA_WORKSPACE\NTLePrismAutomation\NTLePrismAutomation\ePrismReports\

for /f "eol=: delims=" %F in ('dir /b /od *.html') do @set "newest=%F"

"%newest%"
```

Comment: If you would have read the help file for the  `FOR` command you could have answered your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CD /D C:\RAJA_WORKSPACE\NTLePrismAutomation\NTLePrismAutomation\ePrismReports\

for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /od *.html') do @set "newest=%%F"

"%newest%"
```

though I don't think you need the `eol` option. Batch files require double `%` for `for` tokens while in the command prompt they must be single.

Comment: Thank you so much @npocmaka  your answer really helped me a lot

Comment: @rajaram if you feel rhia answer helped to solve your issue please do select it aa the correct answer by selecting the grey tick mark on the left of the answer.

Comment: Yes I ticked once again thanks for your contribution @npocmaka